# Does god appear in visible form to eyes while granting boon?

Tags: gods, yoga, goddess, boon

There are numerous incidents in scriptures where God or goddesses appear to a devotee after performing penance (tapasya) on the name of that particular God or particular goddesses inorder to ask for the wish.

Does God  appear to them in visible form to their eyes or appears in yogic state (experience) or any other way?

Comment: Yes, if the devotee beliefs in the particular form of God. God is formless yet it takes forms, just like form Maya and formless Ishwar, both are inseparable, one cannot conceive one without another. What is material eyes or yogic eyes, these are just divisions of overthinking imagination of some scholar. An animal cant see/understand God even if he takes material avatar and appear in front of its material eyes because of inner oblivion, similar is the case of people who are spiritually blind because of Maya.

Answer (score 1):

Puranas state many things metaphorically.

One such thing is God's appearance before the devotees, talking to them, laughing with them, etc.

The [visions of God](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37694/3869) will be momentary only.  Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa had visions of Kali, which are momentary.  BLISS or SELF REALISATION, which is different from vision of God can only be experienced.

If one is destined to carry out miracles, siddhis will accrue to him/her.  Sri Shirdi Sai performed miracles, whereas Sri Ramana Maharshi did not show miracles.